# I can't connect to clearDB laravel heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, cleardb

I'm trying to connect to clearDB

in database.php file, I did this

```
$databaseUrl = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));
'url' => $databaseUrl,
            'host' => $databaseUrl['host'],
            'port' => $databaseUrl['port'],
            'database' => substr($url["path"], 1),
            'username' => $databaseUrl['user'],
            'password' => $databaseUrl['pass'],
```

I got PHP Notice:  Undefined index: port in /app/config/database.php also the url

Is there any Heroku command to get port, username, password and host .. information ?

Comment: can you `dd(parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL")));` see what you get in your `$databaseUrl` variable?

Answer (score 0):

please try the default MySQL Port 3306:

```
$databaseUrl = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));
'url' => $databaseUrl,
            'host' => $databaseUrl['host'],
            'port' => 3306,
            'database' => substr($url["path"], 1),
            'username' => $databaseUrl['user'],
            'password' => $databaseUrl['pass'],
```